# How to quit "trunk serve" Rust

Tags: rust, yew, trunk-rs

I just started using rust for the web and I have run into a problem where once I call trunk serve I do not know how to stop it.

this must sound like the whole unable to quit vim meme...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Its the standard way to signal a running command-line tool to exit and I don't think `trunk serve` understands anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If ctrl+c doesn't work (for some unknown reason the terminal was stuck and it didn't work for me), you can list the process running on port 8080 (or whatever port you are using to run the server)

`sudo lsof -i:8080`

and then kill the process
`kill -9 PID`

p.s. works on Linux or Mac

Answer (score 0):

To kill from another terminal:

```
kill -9 $(pgrep trunk)
```